# Cross Domain AJAX Call?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, jsonp

```
$.ajax({

      url: 'https://XXXXX.desktop.XXXX.com:9011/iws-merchant/XXXXX.htm',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function (response) {
       str=response;

      },
      error: function( response ) {
          alert( "ERROR:  " + JSON.stringify );
       }
   });
```

It is always going in error block. I am making an AJAX call to a different PORT(Same Domain).

But when i try to hit the same URL in new tab. I am able to see the response.

Any help will be highly appreicated.

Comment: *domain*, *protocol* and *port* have to match. Otherwise the request will fall under the *SOP* restrictions.

Comment: Is the server set up correctly to return a JSONP response? In your example, since you didn't specify a callback parameter, the GET parameter sent to the server would be called 'callback'.

Comment: so we can use JSONP ryt?

Comment: BTW in your error block JSON.stringify by itself isn't going to do anything...I assume that was just a typo

Comment: dataType:"jsonp" will do for me ryt? when the response is succesfull it will come to success handler.

Comment: @Matt yeah thats a typo.sorry for that

Comment: Yes, you can use JSONP. I suggest reading up on it, since it works differently from AJAX. The answer below shows the idea. You need to create a callback function in your response from the server that has the same name as the callback parameter specified by Javascript (in this case jQuery generates the callback parameter for you and appends it to the URL); that's what makes it secure.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But that is not working for me. I am able to see the response in console. But it is going in error block always.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25952/discussion-between-apurv-and-matt-b)

Comment: I couldn't stay on chat for long...in any case it seems maybe you didn't see my suggestion that you add your relevant server-side code to your question. Seeing only the Javascript makes it difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3):

you can use JSONP as Gaurav Agrawal suggested OR you can enable the Access-Control-Allow-Origin for the site who receives ajax request.

Ajax works like this:
Same domain but different port = different domain

if you are using asp.net on your ajax target server you can enable access control adding this in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
<system.webServer>
```

and do yourself a favor and replace "*" with your site url!

in some situation you can need even those keys, just google every function before adding it!

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
<add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="*"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make cross domain AJAX calls using JSON. You need to use JSONP. So instead of returning a regular JsonResult from your controller action write a custom action result that will wrap the JSON in a callback that is passed as parameter:

```
public class JsonpResult : ActionResult
{
    private readonly object _obj;

    public JsonpResult(object obj)
    {
        _obj = obj;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var callbackname = context.HttpContext.Request["callback"];
        var jsonp = string.Format("{0}({1})", callbackname, serializer.Serialize(_obj));
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.Write(jsonp);
    }
}
```

and then have your controller action return this custom action result:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    var result = new[]
    {
        new { Id = 1, Name = "item 1" },
        new { Id = 2, Name = "item 2" },
        new { Id = 3, Name = "item 3" },
    };
    return new JsonpResult(balances);
}
```

Now you could consume this action cross domain:

```
var url = "http://example.com/SomeController/SomeAction/";
$.getJSON(url + '?callback=?', function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```