# Authorize call from external server to controller

Tags: c#, controller

I need to call a controller from my Domain1 to Domain2.

The call is an ajax call to the controller, but it throw me an authorization error.

How I give authorization to the Domain1 to call the controller??

Comment: Your controller has `Authorize` attribute on it?

Comment: I am curious about how you are doing cross domain AJAX requests?

Comment: That is my question... how I've to do the cross domain with ajax... But I found in another question the response http://stackoverflow.com/a/15337364/1221304

Comment: I've found the response to my question
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15337364/1221304
Sorry for the repost!